# Change Icon dynamically in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, icons, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable with a JLabel where i show a given picture if a person is approved(or failed) in a test.I use that renderer:

```
public  class TestCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {    
     List<Student> list=null;  
public TestCellRenderer(List<Student> l){  
    super();  
    this.list=l;       
}      
@Override  
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object object,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {   
         Student s=list.get(row);  
        if(s.getPoints()>=90){  
                setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(okay_path)));}  
        else if(s.getPoints()<90){  
            setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(error_path)));
         }                           
    }         
        setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);            
    return this;  
    }
}//end renderer
```

It works flawless until i have to edit a Student in a JTable row.I open a screen with the contents of that row for edition.Of course, my Table model dont show a value, but a JLabel where i show the picture.But in my Edit frame, i have a box with values.I tried to update after i choose a value but dont works(off course, if i close the main frame and open the imagem is showed modified, but i need to show the rows updated after i close the edit frame(NOTE: all other fields i change in Edit frame updates, less the JLabel).I tried that in MyModel(just relevant parts):

```
StudentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
  Student s=students.get(rowIndex);
 //...many cases
   case GRADE_POINT:
s.setGrade((JLabel)aValue);
   fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex); // Notify update
}
public void setData(List<Student> list){
    this.students.clear();
    for(Student s:list){
             Student student=new Student();
              student.setId(c.getId());
             //...other setters and finally
             student.setGradePointImage(setJLabel(s.getPoints()));
             this.students.add(student);    
            }
    this.fireTableDataChanged();
 }//end set data
public Student getStudent(int rowIndex){
  Student s=students.get(rowIndex);
  Student student=new Student()
  //setters
 return student;
}
public JLabel setJLabel(int value){  
      JLabel l=new JLabel();  
           if(value>=90)  
         l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("...successpath")));  
           else if(value<90)  
         l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("...failedpath")));  
       return l; 
 }
}//end StudentTableModel
```

I have a MainFrame where my table(and the respective rows are showed), and an EditFrame, it always is displayed if the user clicks twice in a row.Everything works fine but the picture update.Oh, i do this in my EditFrame:

```
    if (arg0.getSource() == exitDialog) {  
         model.setData(myList);  
         model.fireTableDataChanged();  
       dispose();//clear EditFrame  
     }//it should update after the EditFrame is closed.
```

It updates everything but the Icon.What i can do to update the Icon? Best Regards,

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Andrew, i thought my code above was enough to describe my problem. and let me explain better, my code, overall, works fine, except when i edit each row in my jtable.All my fields update correctly when i press Exit in my Edit frame except the field with the Icon.If i exit my main frame(where the rows with data are) and open again, the rows are displayed correctly.

Comment: *"..i thought my code above was enough to describe my problem"*  If you were the one reading the code you posted, I might agree..  If you want *me* to look at it, post an SSCCE rather than uncompilable code snippets.  And please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand very well how to format the code down here.In another board i use tags code, and the indentation works fine.I will try to edit my post.